# getOnlinePlayers error class

Tags: java, class, minecraft, bukkit

error in `int j = (arrayOfPlayer = Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()).length;`

[image]

help me?

```
public static void onDisableMod()
{
Player[] arrayOfPlayer;
int j = (arrayOfPlayer = Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()).length;
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
{
  Player online = arrayOfPlayer[i];
  if (modMode.contains(online.getName()))
  {
    online.setMetadata("ModMode", new FixedMetadataValue(Main.pl, Integer.valueOf(1)));
    leaveMod(online);
  }
}
}
```

Comment: If `getOnlinePlayers()` returns a collection, then you can't assign that to an array. Arrays are not the same as collections.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  - *`int j = (arrayOfPlayer = Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()).length;`* please avoid this kind of "smart code".

Answer (score 1):

To address the error at hand, it is a matter of type conversion. As [khelwood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42760626/getonlineplayers-error-class/42801590#comment72636755_42760626) already mentioned in the comments, you are attempting to assign a Java collection to a Java array, which are not one and the same.

If you do need to operate on an array of `Player`, you can use the following to create the array

```
Player[] arrayOfPlayer = Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().toArray( new Player[0] );
```

However, rather than wasting time creating arrays, you can simply iterator over the collection directly in one of two ways: 1) implicitly,

```
for ( Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers() ) {
    if ( modMode.contains( p.getName() ) ) {
        ...
    }
}
```

or, 2) explicitly,

```
Iterator<? extends Player> it = Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().iterator();
while ( it.hasNext() ) {
    Player p = it.next();
    if ( modMode.contains( p.getName() ) ) {
       ...
    }
}
```

The latter approach would be useful if your method modified the underlying collection; not that you could remove elements from `getOnlinePlayers()` as it is an un-modifiable list.

**Update**

I originally hesitated to provide a lambda example given the limited experience of the OP. Lambdas are not necessarily drop-in replacements for all types of iterator tasks without some further examination of the actions to be performed and could result in another and distinct question.

As given above, a possible stream form could be:

```
Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().stream()
    .filter( modMode::contains )
    .forEach( p -> {
        p.setMetadata( "ModMode", new FixedMetadataValue( Main.pl, 1 ) );
        leaveMod( p );
    } );
```

This can be further tweaked toward a functional representation by setting the player's metadata within `leaveMod()`, given that both are always executed for matching players. Assuming that `onDisableMod()` and `leaveMod()` are static methods in class `ModUtils`, the above stream can be further refined and consolidated as follows

```
Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().stream()
    .filter( modMode::contains )
    .forEach( ModUtils::leaveMod );
```

**Special Concerns Iterating On `getOnlinePlayers()`**

For all iteration examples given, caution should be exercised that they are executed in the main thread or a synchronized thread. Furthermore, care must be taken to have no side effects that affect the collection while iterating, such as teleporting, kicking, killing, or firing events via `callEvent()` that do the same.

In such cases, the best practice is to operate on a copy of the collection as in

```
List<Player> olp = new ArrayList<>( Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers() );
```

and proceed with any of the three types of iterations.

Comment: Why using new Player[0]? It's better using the server's maximum player capacity.

Comment: @RoccoDev Let me guess, you are using FindBugs or PMD? First, it should be noted that creating an array via `toArray()` from a collection for the purposes of iteration is a bad design. But if you must, passing a zero-length array puts the onus on the JDK to return a correctly sized array - cleaner and higher quality code. Rolling your own array adds unneeded code and potential errors. Case in point, passing an array sized to Max Capacity, would return an array larger than the number of current players, causing potential NPEs if the array is iterated over blindly. Why add unnecessary risk?

Comment: 1. Nah 2. Thank you for noting that, I barely use arrays in my projects, don't need to.